# How to trigger a particular Chrome extension when a URL contains a certain string

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

So I am very much a newbie to chrome, but I want to figure out how to open and then run a particular extension when a particular URL is open.

To give an example, let's say I have the extension `screencastify` and I want it to run every time the URL `yahoo.com` is seen in any one of my tabs. How would I go about doing that?

Comment: Depends on what you mean by `run`. Anyway, you should really start with the [overview](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/overview).

Comment: You can use `chrome.management.launchApp` to launch apps but unfortunately extensions cannot be launched in that sense